# How To Resize a Video Clip in Python

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, resize, moviepy

I want to resize a video clip in python 2.7.

For example we give "movie.mp4" with 1080p quality
The result should be "movie.mp4" with 360p quality

I Think that there should be solutions with Moviepy. If you know a solution with it.

I would be grateful if you answer me.

Comment: have you read the doc http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html?highlight=resize#moviepy.video.fx.all.resize yet?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here is how you resize a movie with moviepy:
[see the mpviepy doc here](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx/moviepy.video.fx.all.resize.html?highlight=resize#moviepy.video.fx.all.resize)

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("movie.mp4")
clip_resized = clip.resize(height=360) # make the height 360px ( According to moviePy documenation The width is then computed so that the width/height ratio is conserved.)
clip_resized.write_videofile("movie_resized.mp4")
```

You can also tune the quality by adding the parameter `bitrate="500k"` or `bitrate="5000k"` in the last line.

As said above, you could also use ffmpeg directly, it will be simpler if you just need a quick script.

Comment: if you wish to freely set width and height without having to stick to relative scaling of w:h, you can use the `newsize` parameter, ex. `clip_resized = clip.resize(newsize=(my_width,my_height))`

Answer (score 11):

Why not ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf scale=640:360 movie_360p.mp4
```

If you use 640:-2 then, in this example, the scale filter will preserve the aspect ratio and automatically calculate the correct height.

Look at the [H.264 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for additional options.

Comment: how can i use it in python?

Comment: os.system("ffmpeg -i movie.mp4 -vf scale=640:360 movie_360p.mp4")

Comment: Please remember it's not always safe to use `os.system` to launch external programs.

Comment: If you use `640:-2` then, in this example, the scale filter will preserve the aspect ratio and automatically calculate the correct height.

Comment: Thx @LordNeckbeard. Very useful knowledge.

Comment: You could use `subprocess` to run the command... If any errors occur, you would be able to catch them.

Comment: I'm facing Error while getting media from postman and passing in to it ```subprocess.run(f'ffmpeg -i {media} -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 temp_location/{new_uuid}')``` Error is : ```wa.mp4: No such file or directory```

Answer (score 3):

Moviepy Resize function

```
>>> myClip.resize( (460,720) ) # New resolution: (460,720)
>>> myClip.resize(0.6) # width and heigth multiplied by 0.6
>>> myClip.resize(width=800) # height computed automatically.
>>> myClip.resize(lambda t : 1+0.02*t) # slow swelling of the clip
```